# Drawing/warping a rectangular image into a quadrilateral image

Tags: java, image, graphics

I need to draw a BufferedImage within a given quadrilateral.
I want to do that:

[image]

I would like the cat to be deformed to be drawn within the quadrilateral.

`Graphics` objects have different methods to draw images, but only to stretch them along the X and Y axis (See `Graphics.drawImage` methods).

What I am dreaming of is a method `Graphics.drawImage()` where I specify the coordinates of the 4 quadrilateral points. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way to do this with the standard java packages. You could of course implement your own Bilinear or Perspective transform for four corner image warping, but who wants to do all that work.

I think your best bet is to look into the Java Advanced Imaging API (javax.media.JAI). Here is an article that talks about perspective transforms with JAI: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Geom-image-manip.doc.html#55959

Answer (score 1):

You'll find code for how to do it in objective-c here https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit/ . I'm sure it is possible to port to java.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to port it into java.

Comment: Ok, cool. The only thing your really need is the code found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12820877/202451 . You should be able to create a 3d matrix for java with that code. It is the same code as found at the bottom of this file https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit/blob/master/Source/AGQuad.m

Comment: You need a matrix with 4 rows and columns... I don't think this will do http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html