# Draw an Image in arbitrary corners

Tags: java, image, swing, transformation, affinetransform

So i have a normal image. I defined Click- and Drag-Listeners on each corner of the rectangular image. I want to freely transform each of the corners and paint it on the screen.

The AffineTransform class provides transformation possibilities but i couldn't find a way to realize this.

I have implemented the same function in android with the Matrix.setPolytoPoly method. However there is no equivalent in java swing.

Thanks!

Edit:
I would like to illustrate this process with the following image:

[image]

This should happen when i drag one corner to the upper left. Now the problem that i have is, that i don't believe that one can model such a behaviour with a pure 3x3 matrix in an easy way. I looked at the android native code to watch the behaviour, but it's actually pretty deep in the native code.

Comment: Do you want _affine_ or _projective_ geometry?

Comment: as far as i know the projective geometry only applies to display a 3d object to a 2d plane. If so, that's not what i want, as my current image is 2d and should stay 2d (but transformed to any quadrangle).

Comment: An arbitrary quadrilateral would require projective geometry.

Comment: Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: You can find how to do this at:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935053/how-to-distort-an-image-to-any-quadrangle/32871206#32871206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea of how to do that?

Your update shows that the transformation is not [affine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), as parallel lines do not remain parallel. [Java Advanced Imaging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html) (JAI) provides the required projective capabilities through the abstract class [`Warp`](http://download.java.net/media/jai/javadoc/1.1.3/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/Warp.html).