# Graphics (2D) Rotation: Rotate x Axis

Tags: java, swing, rotation, java-2d

I have a `JPanel` in which I draw triangles via the method `drawPolygon`. My Goal is to rotate the graphics around the X axis. I know that there is a method called rotate, but this method rotates only around the Z axis.

How can I rotate a graphic in a `JPanel` around the X axis?

[Example of rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W72Ny.jpg)

[image]

If the Graphics 2D library does not have the functionality to do this kind of rotation, please tell me how can I archive my goal otherwise. I don't mind switching to another GUI type like Java-fx or canvas. (But stay in Java)

Comment: *"How can I rotate a graphic in a `JPanel` around the X axis?"* Do you mean to mirror it as though it started above the X axis and then ended up upside down and below the X axis? If so, an appropriate scaling `AffineTransform` should do it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do not want to mirror it at the X axis, so no scaling. Here is a [visualisation](https://youtu.be/IKB1hWWedMk?t=8m40s) of what I ment.

Comment: Not following a link to a video. Get a screenshot or make a drawing of what you mean.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 2D provides [`AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html), but an [*affine transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) ensures that parallel lines remain parallel after transformation. As an alternative, consider [JavaFX 3D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), which provides a [`PerspectiveCamera`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/camera.htm) for  [*perspective projection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection); this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905744/230513) uses `Rotate.Y_AXIS`, but `Rotate.X_AXIS` will produce the desired effect. Also consider a Java Advanced Imaging `Warp`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16796687/230513), which offers a [`WarpPerspective`](http://download.java.net/media/jai/javadoc/1.1.3/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/WarpPerspective.html) with [`PerspectiveTransform`](http://download.java.net/media/jai/javadoc/1.1.3/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html).

Comment: *"an affine transformation requires that parallel lines remain parallel after transformation"* I'd always wondered about the wording of the docs on that matter (which suggested same to me, but I wasn't sure). It's a pity, given I'd wanted to use a transform to turn a 'flat' map of the world (as might be seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18825844/418556)) into a globe. But the only way I could think to achieve that using core Java was with a transform. Out of luck on that!

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Maybe a `PerspectiveTransform`, cited above, but I'm not sure Mercator has an inverse. Also, I didn't like the word "_requires_".

Comment: See also [`javafx.scene.effect.PerspectiveTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html)