# Is there a way to not stretch the Bitmap when using Matrix.polyToPoly() on a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to do perspective transformation on my bitmap with a given quadrilateral. However, the `Matrix.polyToPoly` function stretches not only the part of the image I want but also the pixels outside the given area, so that a huge image is formed in some edge cases which crashes my app because of OOM.

- Is there any way to sort of drop the pixels outside of the said area to not be stretched?
- Or are there any other possibilities to do a perspective transform which is more memory friendly?

I`m currenty doing it like this:

```
// Perspective Transformation
float[] destination = {0, 0,
        width, 0,
        width, height,
        0, height};

Matrix post = new Matrix();
post.setPolyToPoly(boundingBox.toArray(), 0, destination, 0, 4);
Bitmap transformed = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeight, post, true);
```

where `cropWidth` and `cropHeight` are the size of the bitmap (*I cropped it to the edges of the quadrilateral to save memory*) and `temp` is said cropped bitmap.

Comment: you could try `Canvas#drawBitmapMesh` but i have no idea about how it behaves in terms of memory (you could also try `Canvas#drawVertices` but i really doubt any human ever tried that method :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved it for me. If anyone is curious, this post has all the necessary code: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308856/distorting-an-image-to-a-quadrangle-fails-in-some-cases-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **pskink** I got it working, here is a post with the code in it:

> [Distorting an image to a quadrangle fails in some cases on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308856/distorting-an-image-to-a-quadrangle-fails-in-some-cases-on-android)