# How to distort an layout to any quadrangle?

Tags: android, canvas

I have perspective distort view thanks to this code: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667015/4224024)

I want to put camera preview into it instead of bitmap. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is better, Use opengles if you want to do something with camera perivew.