# Objective-c - How to draw an image as a quadrilateral?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mesh

it's my first month in objective-c, I'm trying to draw an UIImage **(ImageA)** as a quadrilateral on top of another image **(Background Image)**

**ImageA**

[image]

**Background Image** 
[image]

**End Image** 
[image]

What I've tried so far is to 3D Transform the UIImageView containing  **ImageA** with the help of
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606029/864513

Then take a snapshot of the transformed view

```
- (UIImage *)snapshot:(UIView *)view
                size:(CGSize)size
{
  UIImage *viewImage = nil;
  @autoreleasepool {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    BOOL success = [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, size} afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    if (!success || !viewImage) {
      return nil;
    }
  }
  return viewImage;
}
```

Then draw the snapshot image in rectangle in Image Context along with **Background Image**

```
CGRect offsetRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, fileSize.width, fileSize.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fileSize);
[BackgroundImage drawInRect:offsetRect];
[ImageA drawInRect:offsetRect];
UIImage *endImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This method works well but when used in a loop to create a `GIF`. It causes a lot of **memory leaks** and **crashes** in low memory devices!

```
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, [endImage CGImage], (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
```

In Android there is a function called `drawBitmapMesh` that draw the bitmap through the mesh. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmapMesh(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, float[], int, int[], int, android.graphics.Paint)

Is there any way I can draw through the mesh in objective-c. Or if you know a better method to solve my problem, I will forever grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PerspectiveTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform) filter on your image.

Sample code: [Github](https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Advanced-Cookbook/blob/master/C06%20-%20Images/06%20-%20Basic%20Core%20Image/UIImage-CoreImage.m)

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried it, but the result is sketchy, and imageA is not covering the whole area as intended.