# CGPoint on quadrilateral plotted on converted rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, math, transformation, perspective

I can't figure out how to do this (i think my math skills are not that great after all..). I have an array of 4 `CGPoint` objects (A B C D), which is a quadrilateral. On that quadrilateral I have point E.

How can I transform this quadrilateral of 4 `CGPoint` objects to a rectangle, so I can calculate point E on this rectangle?

I can't use the build in `CIPerspectiveCorrection`, because I want the raw CGPoint. I try not to use any external libraries, but if I have to, so be it :)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How would you determine the length/width of the resulting rectangle?

Comment: This type of transformation is called a homography. That keyword should help you in your research

Comment: Ah. @Oritm, this looks kind of similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820877/14351818

Comment: @aheze i have the original cgpoints and the bounds of the view where i want to plot point E.

Comment: @aheze Yes, I found that one as well. I will try to reverse the method!