# Implement Distort option like photoshop in Android App using NDK with opengl es 3.0 C++

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, transformation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3B0.jpg)

In Photoshop we can do distort option in the image. In iOS that option achieve using the CATransform3D matrix. below is the iOS code I get from online in this question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470493/transforming-a-rectangle-image-into-a-quadrilateral-using-a-catransform3d).

```
func rectToQuad(
               rect:CGRect,
               _ x1a:CGFloat, _ y1a:CGFloat,
               _ x2a:CGFloat, _ y2a:CGFloat,
               _ x3a:CGFloat, _ y3a:CGFloat,
               _ x4a:CGFloat, _ y4a:CGFloat    )->(CATransform3D)
           {
        
           let X = rect.origin.x;
           let Y = rect.origin.y;
           let W = rect.size.width;
           let H = rect.size.height;
           print("X, \(X)!")
           print("Y, \(Y)!")
               print("W, \(W)!")
               print("H, \(H)!")
               print("rect tl x, \(x1a), y, \(y1a)")
               print("rect tr x, \(x2a), y, \(y2a)")
               print("rect bl x, \(x3a), y, \(y3a)")
               print("rect br x, \(x4a), y, \(y4a)")
               
           let y21 = y2a - y1a;
           let y32 = y3a - y2a;
           let y43 = y4a - y3a;
           let y14 = y1a - y4a;
           let y31 = y3a - y1a;
           let y42 = y4a - y2a;
               print("y21, \(y21)!")
               print("y32, \(y32)!")
               print("y43, \(y43)!")
               print("y14, \(y14)!")
               print("y31, \(y31)!")
               print("y42, \(y42)!")
           
           let a = -H*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42);
           let b = W*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43);
               print("a, \(a)!")
               print("b, \(b)!")
           let c0 = -H*W*x1a*(x4a*y32 - x3a*y42 + x2a*y43)
           let cx = H*X*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42)
           let cy = -W*Y*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43)
           let c = c0 + cx + cy
               print("c, \(c)!")
            
           let d = H*(-x4a*y21*y3a + x2a*y1a*y43 - x1a*y2a*y43 - x3a*y1a*y4a + x3a*y2a*y4a);
           let e = W*(x4a*y2a*y31 - x3a*y1a*y42 - x2a*y31*y4a + x1a*y3a*y42);
               print("d, \(d)!")
               print("e, \(e)!")
           let f0 = -W*H*(x4a*y1a*y32 - x3a*y1a*y42 + x2a*y1a*y43)
           let fx = H*X*(x4a*y21*y3a - x2a*y1a*y43 - x3a*y21*y4a + x1a*y2a*y43)
           let fy = -W*Y*(x4a*y2a*y31 - x3a*y1a*y42 - x2a*y31*y4a + x1a*y3a*y42)
           let f = f0 + fx + fy
               print("f, \(f)!")
           let g = H*(x3a*y21 - x4a*y21 + (-x1a + x2a)*y43);
           let h = W*(-x2a*y31 + x4a*y31 + (x1a - x3a)*y42);
               print("g, \(g)!")
               print("h, \(h)!")
           let i0 = H*W*(x3a*y42 - x4a*y32 - x2a*y43)
           let ix = H*X*(x4a*y21 - x3a*y21 + x1a*y43 - x2a*y43)
           let iy = W*Y*(x2a*y31 - x4a*y31 - x1a*y42 + x3a*y42)
           var i = i0 + ix + iy
               print("i, \(i)!")
        
           let kEpsilon:CGFloat = 0.0001;
           if(fabs(i) < kEpsilon) { i = kEpsilon * (i > 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0); }
        
           return CATransform3D(m11:a/i, m12:d/i, m13:0, m14:g/i,
                               m21:b/i, m22:e/i, m23:0, m24:h/i,
                               m31:0, m32:0, m33:1, m34:0,
                               m41:c/i, m42:f/i, m43:0, m44:1.0)
           }
```

I try to implement that matrix in Android App using NDK and opengles 3.0 c++

```
void TransformTool::rectToQuad(Rect rect, Point tl,Point tr,Point bl,Point br){
        float* worldViewMatrix = dynamic_cast<ImageLayer *>(imageLayer)->getWorldViewMatrix();
        long double W = rect.width;
        long double H = rect.height;
        long double X = 0;
        long double Y = 0;

        CCELogError("W: %Lf, H: %Lf",W,H);
        CCELogError("X: %Lf, Y: %Lf",X,Y);

        long double x1a = tl.x;
        long double y1a = tl.y;
        long double x2a = tr.x;
        long double y2a = tr.y;
        long double x3a = bl.x;
        long double y3a = bl.y;
        long double x4a = br.x;
        long double y4a = br.y;

        long double y21 = y2a - y1a;
        long double y32 = y3a - y2a;
        long double y43 = y4a - y3a;
        long double y14 = y1a - y4a;
        long double y31 = y3a - y1a;
        long double y42 = y4a - y2a;

        CCELogError("y21: %Lf",y21);
        CCELogError("y32: %Lf",y32);
        CCELogError("y43: %Lf",y43);
        CCELogError("y14: %Lf",y14);
        CCELogError("y31: %Lf",y31);
        CCELogError("y42: %Lf",y42);

        long double a = -H*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42);
        CCELogError("a: %Lf",a);
        long double b = W*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43);
        CCELogError("b: %Lf",b);
        long double c0 = -H*W*x1a*(x4a*y32 - x3a*y42 + x2a*y43);
        long double cx = H*X*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42);
        long double cy =-W*Y*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43);
        long double c = c0 + cx + cy;

        CCELogError("c: %Lf",c);
        long double d = H*(-x4a*y21*y3a + x2a*y1a*y43 - x1a*y2a*y43 - x3a*y1a*y4a + x3a*y2a*y4a);
        long double e = W*(x4a*y2a*y31 - x3a*y1a*y42 - x2a*y31*y4a + x1a*y3a*y42);
        CCELogError("d: %Lf",d);
        CCELogError("e: %Lf",e);
        long double f0 = -W*H*(x4a*y1a*y32 - x3a*y1a*y42 + x2a*y1a*y43);
        long double fx = H*X*(x4a*y21*y3a - x2a*y1a*y43 - x3a*y21*y4a + x1a*y2a*y43);
        long double fy = -W*Y*(x4a*y2a*y31 - x3a*y1a*y42 - x2a*y31*y4a + x1a*y3a*y42);
        long double f = f0 + fx + fy;
        CCELogError("f: %Lf",f);
        long double g = H*(x3a*y21 - x4a*y21 + (-x1a + x2a)*y43);
        long double h = W*(-x2a*y31 + x4a*y31 + (x1a - x3a)*y42);
        CCELogError("g: %Lf",g);
        CCELogError("h: %Lf",h);

        long double i0 = H*W*(x3a*y42 - x4a*y32 - x2a*y43);
        long double ix = H*X*(x4a*y21 - x3a*y21 + x1a*y43 - x2a*y43);
        long double iy = W*Y*(x2a*y31 - x4a*y31 - x1a*y42 + x3a*y42);
        long double i = i0 + ix + iy;
        CCELogError("i: %Lf",i);
        long double kEpsilon = 0.0001;

        if(abs(i) < kEpsilon){
            i = kEpsilon * (i > 0 ? 1.0f : -1.0f);
        }
        CCELogError("i: %Lf",i);

       
        long double m11 = a/i;
        long double m12 = d/i;
        long double m13 = 0;
        long double m14 = (g/i);
        long double m21 = b/i;
        long double m22 = e/i;
        long double m23 = 0;
        long double m24 = (h/i);
        long double m31 = 0;
        long double m32 = 0;
        long double m33 = 1;
        long double m34 = 0;
        long double m41 = c/i;
        long double m42 = f/i;
        long double m43 = 0;
        long double m44 = 1;
        CCELogError("a/i: %Lf",m11);
        CCELogError("b/i: %Lf",m21);
        CCELogError("c/i: %.15Lf",m41);
        CCELogError("d/i: %.15Lf",m12);
        CCELogError("e/i: %Lf",m22);
        CCELogError("f/i: %.15Lf",m42);
        CCELogError("g/i: %Lf",m14);
        CCELogError("h/i: %Lf",m24);


        Matrix::translate(tempViewMatrix1,
                          -this->focalPointTranslation[0],
                          -this->focalPointTranslation[1],
                          false);
        tempViewMatrix1[0] = m11;
        tempViewMatrix1[1] = m12;
        tempViewMatrix1[2] = m13;
        tempViewMatrix1[3] = m14;
        tempViewMatrix1[4] = m21;
        tempViewMatrix1[5] = m22;
        tempViewMatrix1[6] = m23;
        tempViewMatrix1[7] = m24;
        tempViewMatrix1[8] = m31;
        tempViewMatrix1[9] = m32;
        tempViewMatrix1[10] = m33;
        tempViewMatrix1[11] = m34;
        tempViewMatrix1[12] = m41;
        tempViewMatrix1[13] = m42;
        tempViewMatrix1[14] = m43;
        tempViewMatrix1[15] = m44;

        Matrix::translate(tempViewMatrix1,
                          this->focalPointTranslation[0],
                          this->focalPointTranslation[1],
                          false);
       
        Matrix::multiply(transformViewMatrix,transformViewMatrix,tempViewMatrix1,false);
    }
```

but this does not give correct transform. I try to use `viewmatrix` to change the position of the vertex of images.

I need to find a matrix that works distort on images in opengles 3.0.